# Webrtc collection is not showing in firebase database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webrtc

i am working on webrtc video call demo but when I create offer or answer , then there is no collection created in firestore and that's why remote user is not joining . can anyone tell me what's wrong here.

```
const handleCallButton = async () => {
    // Reference Firestore collections for signaling
    const callDoc = firestore.collection("calls").doc();
    const offerCandidates = callDoc.collection("offerCandidates");
    const answerCandidates = callDoc.collection("answerCandidates");

    callInput.value = callDoc.id;

    // Get candidates for caller, save to db
    pc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
      event.candidate && offerCandidates.add(event.candidate.toJSON());
    };

    // Create offer
    const offerDescription = await pc.createOffer();
    await pc.setLocalDescription(offerDescription);
  };
```

for more details , here is link of code and working demo -
https://github.com/Tejendrasrajawat/webRtc/blob/main/src/App.js
https://glittering-croquembouche-59f35a.netlify.app/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you can try

```
const roomWithOffer = {
    'offer': {
      type: offerDescription.type,
      sdp: offerDescriptionr.sdp,
    },
  };
  await callDoc.set(roomWithOffer);
```

to substitute line 79 to 84.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).